# How to keep alive task into Foreground Service in standby / Doze mode?

Tags: android, foreground

I have a foreground service that manages some timer counters based on each 1s from a task. But, in **standby mode** or **doze mode**, the task is switch to pause by the system. This behavior is not present on all the mobiles, but on Huawei, Xiaomi is very often.

Have you got some ideas guys to fix this trouble?

Thank you very much

My service:

```
public class MyTimerService extends Service {

@SuppressLint("WakelockTimeout")
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent == null) return START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY;

    // First at all, generate system notification with foreground link
    createNotification();

    ...

    mExecutorFuture = MyApplication.getInstance().getExecutorServiceScheduler().
                scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> {

                    lockCPU()

                    ...

                    unlockCPU()

                    }
                }, 0, 1/* every 1 second*/, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    return START_STICKY;
}

private void lockCPU() {
    PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    mWakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, TAG);
    mWakeLock.acquire();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    resetSound();

    super.onDestroy();

    ...

    if (mExecutorFuture != null) {
        mExecutorFuture.cancel(true);
    }
}

private void unlockCPU() {
    if (mWakeLock != null && mWakeLock.isHeld()) {
        mWakeLock.release();
        mWakeLock = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What **exactly** are you doing every second?

Comment: I treat some timers and according the values I send event (EventBus) to UI and I play sound (bip timer).

Comment: Unless you are beeping every second, there should be more efficient approaches that do not involve getting control (and keeping the CPU on) every second. In general, users don't like apps that waste power, and some manufacturers are fairly aggressive about preventing apps from continuously running in the background. As Tang Ke points out, you can try to get the user to add your app to the battery optimization whitelist, but that is not guaranteed to help.

Comment: No, whitelist doesn't effect. I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to request user to authenticate your app to running in background

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName())));
```